# Prove that lim is 0.

Tags: analysis

> Prove that $$\lim_{x\to0}\sqrt{|x|}\sin\left(\frac1x+x^{10}\right)=0.$$

How do I show in a rigorous way that this limit as $x\to 0$ equals $0$ ?
Any tips or suggestions would be great!

Comment: Tip: $\sin$ is bounded.

Comment: A word of advice: You are using the terminology incorrectly: The limit does not go anywhere, it is a fixed number. The limit *equals* $0$. You could say that "The function approaches $0$ as $x$ approaches $0$."

Comment: @O.L. since sin is bounded. the limit is 0 as x approaches 0?
what about square root of x?

Comment: In calculus class, this is called the "Squeeze Theorem", but a calc book might not have a proof you would like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since
$|\sin(anything)| \le 1$,
$|\sqrt{|x|}\sin(anything)| 
\le |\sqrt{|x|}|$,
and since
$\lim_{x \to 0} |\sqrt{|x|}|
= 0$
(assuming you can prove this),
the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$sin(x)\leq 1$

$\iff$ $sin(\frac{1}{x}+x^{10})\leq 1$

$\therefore \lim = \lim(\sqrt(|x|)*1)=0$